# Javacc : nested-if-statements

Tags: javacc

I generated a parser by JavaCC. Then, I would count the number of nested `if`s in my method.
My File .jjt is :

```
// TestParser.jjt
PARSER_BEGIN(TestParser)

public class TestParser {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws ParseException {
    TestParser parser = new TestParser(new java.io.StringReader(args[0]));
    SimpleNode root = parser.program();
    root.dump("");
  }
}

PARSER_END(TestParser)


TOKEN : { <id : ["a"-"z","A"-"Z","_"] (["a"-"z","A"-"Z","0"-"9","_"])* }
 /* Reserved words */
 TOKEN  :
 { < IF > | <begin> | <end> | < THEN > | < ELSEIF >|  <STRING> |  < ENDIF > |...}


SimpleNode MyProgram() #PROGRAM :
{}
 {
 (MyMethod ())*   {return jjtThis;}

 }


void MyMethod () #MyMethod : {}
 {
 <begin> id() "(" (Argument ())* ")" {}
 (Statement ()) *
  <end>
 }


Token id() #ID:
{
  Token t;
}
{
t=<ID> {jjtThis.value = t.image; return t;}
}

 void Argument() #argument : {}
 {
 <String>  id()
 <int>  id()
 }

 void statement () #statement : {}
 {
 ifElseStatement ()
 // here other statement

 }
 void ifElseStatement () #ifElseStatement :{}
 {
   < IF > BooleanStructure() < THEN >
   (
     statement ()
   )*
   (
     < ELSEIF > BooleanStructure() < THEN >
     (
       statement ()
     )*
   )*
     < ELSE >
     (
       statement ()
     )*

   < ENDIF >
 }
 }
```

I can generated the AST for input file stream. But, My question how I can traverse Tree by Design VISITOR Because I want Count nested If statement. Thank you in advance

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this site expects English as the working language

Comment: @Pablo: the question is in English now :)

Comment: @kadahowa: it seems that your grammar has unbalanced curly braces, is it the whole text or is there some missing code?

Comment: What's the context. Are you doing this for a class assignment, for work, for your thesis?

Comment: I want this for training because I am student.

Comment: I coded the file .jjt like this:

Comment: I can generated the AST for input file stream. But, My question how I can traverse Tree by Design VISITOR 
Because I want Count nested If statement.

Thank you  in advance

Answer (score 2):

Use the `VISITOR=true` option. That will generate an accept method for each node class and will create an interface that your visitor class should implement. See the manual at https://javacc.java.net/doc/JJTree.html .

If you also use `MULTI=true`, the interface is more extensive.

Comment: Can you explain me more. Thank you very much In advance.

Comment: Well I don't know what you mean by counting nested ifs. Do you want to know the depth of the maximally deep if? Do you want to know how many "if" statements there are at each leve? Does an "if" inside a "while" count as nested?  So your question is far too vague to be answered in more detail. In any case however you define nested ifs writing the appropriate visitor class is a a mere matter of programming.

Comment: I want to know the depth of the maximally deep if AND  want to know how many "if" statements there are at each level. thank you in advance.

Comment: So make a visitor with a counter `k` and an array `d`, both initialized to 0. Whenever the visitor enters and if, it does `d[k] +=1 ; k +=1;`. Whenever the visitor leaves an if it does `k-=1`.